# PHP Throwing error about undefined function on a defined function

Tags: php

I have a PHP class that defines basic functions to retrieve information and data about a user, I'm trying to us the gravatar function but it keeps throwing this error,

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::get_gravatar() in /home/bronypla/public_html/beta/cms_pages/user/profile.php on line 20`

This is the code for **profile.php**

```
<?php 
get_header(); 
$args = $_SESSION['PAGE_ARGS'];

$selected_username = $args[0];
if(!does_user_exist($selected_username)):
?>

<div class="site-wrap">    
  <div class="container text-center">
    <p class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Whoops!</strong> That user doesn't exist or couldn't be found, I did find a Luna though!</p>
    <img src="<?php echo get_website(); ?>/imgs/luna_happy.png" style="width: auto; max-height: 50%;" />
  </div>
</div>

<?php
else:

$selected_user = new User($selected_username);
?>

<div class="site-wrap">
  <div class="site-content container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="<?php echo $selected_user->get_gravatar(); ?>">
        </div>
        <h1><?php echo $selected_username; ?></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
endif;
get_footer(); 
?>
```

And this is the code for **user.inc.php**

```
<?php
require_once('functions.inc.php');

class User
{
private $username;

function __construct($username) {
    $this->username = $username;
}

public function get_username() {
    return $this->username;
}

public function get_property($name, $table = "Users")
{
    $database = new Database();
    $database->open_connection();
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($database->query("SELECT `$name` FROM `$table` WHERE `Username`='$this->username'"));
    $database->close_connection();

    if(!$database->get_error())
        $_SESSION['error'] = base64_encode($database->get_error());

    return $result[$name];

}

public function set_property($name, $value, $table = "Users")
{
    $database = new Database();
    $database->open_connection();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($database->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table` LIKE '$name'")) === 0)
        $database->query("ALTER TABLE `Users` ADD $name VARCHAR( 1024 )");

    $database->query("UPDATE `$table` SET `$name`='$value' WHERE `Username`='$this->username'");

    if(!$database->get_error())
        $_SESSION['error'] = base64_encode($database->get_error());

    $database->close_connection();
}

public function get_gravatar($s = 250, $d = 'mm', $r = 'pg', $img = false, $atts = array() ) 
{
    $email = $this->get_property('Email');
    $url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
    $url .= md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
    $url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";
    if ( $img ) {
        $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
        foreach ( $atts as $key => $val )
            $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
        $url .= ' />';
    }
    return $url;
}

public static function current_user()
{
    $hash = $_COOKIE['cmslogin-hash'];

    if(empty($hash))
        return FALSE;

    $database = new Database();
    $database->open_connection();

    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($database->query("SELECT `Username` FROM `Users_Login` WHERE `Hash`='$hash'"));

    if(!$database->get_error())
        $_SESSION['error'] = base64_encode($database->get_error());

    if(!$result)
        return false;

    return new User($result['Username']);
}
}
?>
```

I can not seem to find the problem here but it is most likely something simple that I'm missing and can't see it.

Thanks for the help,

Liam Haworth.

Comment: Can you var_dump() the variable to see what it really looks like?

Comment: `object(User)#1 (1) { ["username":"User":private]=> string(14) "TheAuzzieBrony" }`

Comment: Are you loading the right User class, and not some other version? This kind of mistakes happens sometimes

Comment: It is weird... Try `var_dump(get_class_methods($selected_user));` and check that `get_gravatar` is there just to be on the safe side, it might be that it's not actually the same class being loaded.

Comment: turned out dreamweaver wasn't uploading the updated file, I have fixed it now, thank you for all the help